# Flutter ternary conditional is null and not subtype of bool

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Text(
  data?["success"] != null ? "Success" : "Failure",
  style: TextStyle(
    color: data?["success"] ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
    fontSize: 15.0),
  )
),
```

> _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool')

Sometimes `data["success"]` has a response of `null` but it usually is `true` or `false` `boolean`.

I'm using the spacexdata.com api for launches: https://docs.spacexdata.com/#bc65ba60-decf-4289-bb04-4ca9df01b9c1 and it is not data I control.

Hoping someone can help

Comment: you first need to check if data as null or not and then check if data?["success"] is also null or not.

Comment: can you show how the data is fetched or a sample response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this `data?["success"] != null ?` is your way of checking success, you need to apply it further down, too:

```
Text(
  data?["success"] != null ? "Success" : "Failure",
  style: TextStyle(
    color: data?["success"] != null ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
    fontSize: 15.0),
  )
),
```

Obviously, I have no clue if handling the data that way is "correct", but you should no longer get errors, your success is green and your failure is red.